# Rally App SDK 2.0 / SharePoint integration

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sdk, rally

I have created a series of custom apps, using the 2.0pX SDK, which I would like to distribute to others within the company using SharePoint. In all the examples I have found on how to do this, version 1.XX of the SDK is being used. Is it a possibility at this point to share 2.0 apps via SharePoint? If not, is this integration planned for a future release of the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, AppSDK2 Preview doesn't provide "LoginKey-like" functionality. Right now the focus for Rally engineering is on getting the finishing touches on AppSDK2 in order to get the toolkit to GA.

AppSDK2 "LoginKey-like" capability is definitely on the radar screen for AppSDK2 since being able to "surface" Rally data to external web pages without the need for end user authentication is very popular - so this will likely be on the roadmap once the toolkit is GA.